# How to INCLUDE a CPT in the already existing category and tag taxonomy that is with posts

Tags: wordpress

I created a CPT and have it use the same taxonomies as posts (tags and categories) so they share them. However, for some reason, the CPT posts don't show up in the category or tag pages.

Here's my CPT code:

```
register_post_type( 'app_video', array(
'labels'              => array(
    'name'               => __( 'Videos', 'app' ),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'Video', 'app' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'app' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add new Video', 'app' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Video', 'app' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Video', 'app' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Video', 'app' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Video', 'app' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Videos', 'app' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No videos found', 'app' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No videos found in trash', 'app' ),
),
'public'              => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive'         => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'capability_type'     => 'post',
'taxonomies'          => array( 'category','post_tag' ),
'hierarchical'        => false,
'_edit_link'          => 'post.php?post=%d',
'rewrite'             => array(
    'slug'       => 'videos',
    'with_front' => false,
),
'query_var'           => true,
'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
```

) );

What do I need to do to have it show up on the category and tag pages?

Comment: Dumb question: did you tag / categorize your video posts already?

Comment: Yes, i tagged and categorized two different CPT with two different tags and categories.